# JSoup $ sign in id tag

Tags: java, jsoup

How can I use JSoup special characters in a tag attribute selector?.

For example:

```
id=HRS_CE_JO_EXT_I_HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID$1
```

The usual selection syntax doesn't work:

```
element.select("span#HRS_CE_JO_EXT_I_HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID$0");
```

Of course, as long as the special characters are towards the end, "start with" syntax can be used, but it is a kind-of-ugly work around..

Comment: have you tried replacing $ with \\$

Answer (score 1):

You can try the *attribute selector* instead:

```
final String html = "<div id=HRS_CE_JO_EXT_I_HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID$1>A</div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

//                         whatever tag
//                             |
Element element = doc.select("div[id=HRS_CE_JO_EXT_I_HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID$1]").first();
//                                 |                  |
//                           attribute = id     attribute value

System.out.println(element);
```

**Output:**

```
<div id="HRS_CE_JO_EXT_I_HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID$1">
 A
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks! It never occurred to me, that the two worked differently in terms of odd chars.